# Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator: diacritics shown wrong after install

Tags: unicode, keyboard, non-unicode

I'm trying to make a keyboard for myself in Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator based on German with two additional diacritics: a caron (wedge above the character) and a macron (dash above the character). I'm defining these as dead keys. Everything works fine in "Test Keyboard Layout".

Once I build and install, it works fine for the macron (dash) but the carons are displayed as breves, i.e. instead of a little wedge over the vowels, I get a little semi-circle.

I do get errors like the one below on in the verification log, but a) in the actual log, the character displays fine (i.e. the issue isn't encoding, which is set to UTF-8) and b) I also get that same error for the macron but that one works.

Here's the error:
"The dead key ̌ (U+030c) when combined with I (U+0049) returns Ǐ (U+01cf), but Ǐ (U+01cf) is not on the default system code page (1252) of the German (Germany) language you specified. This may cause compatibility problems in non-Unicode applications."

I also tried setting the language of my custom keyboard to US and a bunch of other languages in case that made a difference, but it looks like US and DE use the same code page, so it shouldn't matter.

My suspicion is that it has something to do with the limit of the language code page or unicode range or something, but then again someone seemed to have managed to get it working with a US base (same code page), so... I don't know. (And then why can I copy/paste it from other texts and insert it from the character map? Is the issue maybe directly in the keyboard driver?)

All thoughts are appreciated!

EDIT: It's now the next day and now even the dashed characters don't work anymore! Re-installed the keyboard, nothing ò_ó